# How do I convert a tuple of tuples of strings to words?

Tags: python

''.join function in python work with strings in one tuple. Suppose we have tuple of 'nested' tuples of strings as shown down in txt input

There is some structure here as tree. There is roots of the words. For example, sea seam have 'se' as one root. They also share 'se' as a root with 'sex' and 'seven' but 's' only is a root for other word 'soup'. ram doesn't have any sharing root.

```
   _ _ _ r _ _ _ a _ _ _ m%
  /
 /          _ _ _ o _ _ _ u _ _ _ p
-          /
 \        /          _ _ _a% _ _ _ m%
  \_ _ _ s          /
          \        /
           \_ _ _ e _ _ _ x%
                   \
                    \_ _ _ v _ _ _ e _ _ _ n%


#input
txt = "(ram%+s(e(a%m%+x%+ven%)+o%up%))"

#output
[ram, sea, seam, sex, seven, soup]
```

Outputs should be a list of words with roots which separates using '+'. In mind and sequenced according to the following two conditions

```
+ refers to start new word

% refers to the end of the word
```

Hope you get the question what I mean and wish you can help.

Comment: This is a lengthy problem (probably hw, interview, or coding challenge). Regardless SO is not a coding service.  What code have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The way you explained the question doesn't make the most sense (to me, at least), but here's my shot at answering it:

The input format you provided, while nice, is not directly usable in python code. Here's a valid way you could represent the notation used in your input in python:

```
# empty root node, use empty string
txt = ("", "ram", ("s", "oup", ("e", "am", "x", "ven")))
```

Where each each tuple follows the form:

```
(root, additions)
```

Where `root` is a string and `additions` is a tuple or a string.
To parse `txt` into a valid list, you could write a recursive function, like so:

```
def parse(x):
    # return [x] if x is just a string.
    if isinstance(x, str): return [x]

    root, additions = x[0], x[1:] 

    words = []
    for addition in additions:

        # recursively 'flatten' all additions in current node
        sub_additions = parse(addition)

        # add the root word to each sub_addition
        sub_additions = [root + addition for addition in sub_additions]

        # add the new sub additions to the list
        words = words + sub_additions

    return words
```

To use `parse`, simply call it: for example, `parse(txt)`.

Caveats:

- Not sure if this is the easiest or most pythonic way to do this.
- Will only work with a nested set of tuples and strings, will not accept other types.
- Does not use the exact input format you used in your answer. (Because it's not valid python?)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think your work is great. But I think my input was not right as tuple. It's string of tuple like this
txt = "(ram%+s(e(a%m%+x%+ven%)+o%up%))".